# OGLES 2 Native Android: eglCreateWindowSurface Arguments

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, arguments

I have a funny event with one application in development using OpenGL ES on native NDK C++ for Android. The program compiles and runs with no problem. However if I decide to make a unit test and debug the code, it complains with the following message:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: 
    void * eglCreateWindowSurface(void *, void *, unsigned long int, 
                                                         const int *) '
```

Which is related to the last line from the following code snapshot:

```
    EGLint lFormat, lNumConfigs, lErrorResult;
    EGLConfig lConfig;
    // Defines display requirements. 16bits mode here.
    const EGLint lAttributes[] = {
        EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5, EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6, EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, EGL_RENDER_BUFFER, EGL_BACK_BUFFER,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    // Retrieves a display connection and initializes it.
    packt_Log_debug("Connecting to the display.");
    mDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
    if (mDisplay == EGL_NO_DISPLAY) goto ERROR;
    if (!eglInitialize(mDisplay, NULL, NULL)) goto ERROR;
    // Selects the first OpenGL configuration found.
    packt_Log_debug("Selecting a display config.");
    if(!eglChooseConfig(mDisplay, lAttributes, &lConfig, 1,
        &lNumConfigs) || (lNumConfigs <= 0)) goto ERROR;
    // Reconfigures the Android window with the EGL format.
    packt_Log_debug("Configuring window format.");
    if (!eglGetConfigAttrib(mDisplay, lConfig,
        EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &lFormat)) goto ERROR;
    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(mApplication->window, 0, 0, lFormat);
    // Creates the display surface.
    packt_Log_debug("Initializing the display.");
    mSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(mDisplay, lConfig, mApplication->window, NULL);
```

I already looked on OGLES references, but all different things I tried did not work out yet.

Comment: Don't you have some additional text of error message before one you posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing 'mApplication->window' for 'EGLNativeWindowType window' solved the problem.